# Cannot receive correct result in Python when simulating SUMIFS Function in Excel

Tags: python, excel, sumifs

I’m using Google Colab to code Python. There are my codes:

from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

df = pd.read_excel('TEST.xlsx')

df1 = df.loc[(df["H"] == 9) & (df["M"] >= 0) & (df["M"] <= 4) & (df["TYPE"] == "M") & (df["UO"] > 0), "V"]

result = df1.sum()

result

This is the result from Google Colab:

Saving TEST.xlsx to TEST (2).xlsx

0

This is my Excel Function:
=SUMIFS(G:G,N:N,9,O:O,">="&0,O:O,"<="&4,J:J,"<>"&0)

If I calculate in Excel, the result is 5762.  But when I use Google Colab, the result is:

Saving TEST.xlsx to TEST (1).xlsx

<bound method Series.sum of Series([], Name: V, dtype: int64)>

Why I cannot receive the result of 5762 on Google Colab. Please help me check my code and give me some advice.

My file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YYuWDxsBsBa2dNo50kXuQPl4LhszMlDX/view?usp=sharing

Thank you so much. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You want [`.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) to call the method of the Series, not simply `.sum` (which is a reference to it)!

Comment: I changed my code to: result = df1.sum(). The result is 0. But my desired result is 5762.


I don't know why, can you take some time to help me. Thank you so much

Comment: this will probably help you more as you haven't provided a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the body of your question, but a link somewhere https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .. does calling [.head()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) on `df` show what you expect?

Comment: I sent my Excel file on this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YYuWDxsBsBa2dNo50kXuQPl4LhszMlDX/view?usp=sharing

and my code in my post. You can apply my Excel Function in my post to any cell in my Excel file. The reuslt of my Excel Function is 5762, but the reuslt of my Excel Function

Please help me. Thank you so much  :)